# Why is perl regex hanging?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code (which uses a recursive regex).   Things seem to work fine, except at one particular place, where I have an unmatched brace.   I'm trying to understand what exactly is causing the hang.   I have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;
use Data::Dumper;

my $matchBracePtrn =    qr/(?<brace>\((?:[^()]+|(?&brace))+\))/;
my $mkVarPtrn =         qr/\$(?:\w|${matchBracePtrn})/;

# my $testString='$(a) $(a $(c)';   # OK: reports $(a) and $(c)...
# my $testString='$(foreach i,$(LIST),$(eval $(call foo,$i)))'; # OK
my $testString='$(a) $(foreach i,$(LIST),$(eval $(call foo,$i))'; #not OK!

while ($testString =~ /($mkVarPtrn)/g) {
    print "$1\n"
}
```

This outputs:

```
$(a)
```

and then hangs.   This is perl 5.22.0, in case that matters.

Comment: It is catastrophic backtracking. The `(?<brace>\((?:[^()]+|(?&brace))+\))` should actually be `(?<brace>\((?:[^()]++|(?&brace))+\))`. See [online demo](https://rextester.com/BJHD11096).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?<brace>\((?:[^()]+|(?&brace))+\))` pattern causes [*catastrophic backtracking*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

In order to fix the recursive pattern, either use a `++` possessive quantifier with `[^()]`, `[^()]++`, or use an atomic group instead of the non-capturing group, `(?>[^()]+|(?&brace))+`.

So, use either of

```
my $matchBracePtrn =    qr/(?<brace>\((?:[^()]++|(?&brace))+\))/;
my $matchBracePtrn =    qr/(?<brace>\((?>[^()]+|(?&brace))+\))/;
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/BJHD11096).

Comment: The two solutions are not equivalent. (The second is equivalent to `(?:[^()]+|(?&brace))++`, not `(?:[^()]++|(?&brace))+`) Is that intentional?

Comment: The only intention is to *forbid backtracking* into the patterns quantified in the group. There are two ways to do this: either with a possessive quantifier on these items or an atomic group. Both yield the same output.

Comment: But you didn't apply the possessive quantifier and the atomic group to the same thing

Comment: And that does not matter. Those are the solutions.

Comment: Re "*There are two ways to do this: either with a possessive quantifier on these items or an atomic group.*", I'm still hooked on the fact that this this is not what you showed in your answer. You didn't just change the whether possessive quantifier or atomic group is used used, but you changed which items it applies to. Your comments don't acknowledge this, so my question remains unanswered: Is that intentional? Cause your answer and your comments make it sound like it isn't. This lack of clarity should be addressed.

Comment: The second solution (`qr/(?<brace>\((?>[^()]+|(?&brace))+\))/`) is more efficient than the first (`qr/(?<brace>\((?:[^()]++|(?&brace))+\))/` aka `qr/(?<brace>\((?:(?>[^()]+)|(?&brace))+\))/`) since it prevents more backtracking.